# Spark read data from s3: How to config "fs.s3a.multipart.size" correctly for a Spark Context?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop

I'm creating a Spark job to read data from AWS3 server. This is the code to create and config Spark Session and Spark Context:

`spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("mongopipeline").master("local")`
`.config("spark.executor.memory","1g")`
`.config("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://yourway:yourway2020@13.212.171.210:27017/yourway.job_description?authSource=admin")`

`.config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true")`

`.config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions","-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true")`

`.getOrCreate()`

`spark_context = spark.sparkContext`

`spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "XXXX")`
`spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "XXXX")`
`spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")`

Then I get an Error: `: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100M"`

I searched for this problem and found out this was caused by the value of config `"fs.s3a.multipart.size"`, which is "100M" by default. Therefore I added one more configuration line of code which is:

`spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.multipart.size", "104857600")`

However, I got another error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`, which probably be caused by the added configuration. So how could I set `"fs.s3a.multipart.size"`correctly?

More information:

python 3.9.2; spark 3.1.1; scala 2.12.13; aws-java-sdk 1.7.4; hadoop-aws 2.7.1

spark-submit cmd: `spark-submit --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1 /path/to/file/main.py`

OS: macOS BigSur 11.2.3

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I haven't install hadoop along with spark, and the parameter I want to set configuration belonging to hadoop.

After installing spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7, I opened terminal inside this folder and ran the spark-submit command successfully.

About steps to install spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7, you can visited:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyspark/pyspark_environment_setup.htm